# Data Warehouse -- Generating natural keys to be used in WHERE clauses

Tags: postgresql, data-warehouse

I need to repeatedly retrieve a group of records from a data warehouse fact table based on multiple where conditions.

Not

```
WHERE (user_d=1 OR user_id=2) AND (branch_id=1 OR branch_id=2)
```

but

```
WHERE (user_id=1 AND branch_id=1) OR (branch_id=2 AND branch_id=2)
```

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
... WHERE CONCAT(user_id,branch_id) IN ('11','22 )
```

and then creating a new column, turning the concat into a natural key which will be created on insert:

```
WHERE new_key IN ('11','22')
```

This will allow:

- SELECT queries to avoid JOINS. I have input of user_id and branch_id, and can generate that in the application.
- I can put a unique constraint on the key field, and then can use an UPSERT.

Is generating a natural key like this strictly for easier lookups bad practice?

**CLARIFICATION**

I want to use an IN clause because I will have a lot of combined values to lookup.

I won't have IDs to build the new_key or look it up, it will be values.

I think I answered my own question. It's bad practice because it's redundant data.

The CONCAT will be a better choice off a JOIN. To optimize, instead of storing values in the database, it's better to add a key-value store in front like redis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use composite keys. If the table's natural key is `(user_id, branch_id)`, use that.

```
CREATE TABLE whatever
(
    user_id ....,
    branch_id ...,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, branch_id);
);
```

In joins you can do it like you showed:

```
SELECT ...
FROM sometable s
INNER JOIN whatever w ON (s.user_id = w.user_id AND s.branch_id = w.branch_id)
```

or pairwise:

```
SELECT ...
FROM sometable s
INNER JOIN whatever w ON (s.user_id, s.branch_id) = (w.user_id = w.branch_id)
```

For use with `IN`, use lists of anonymous records:

```
SELECT ...
FROM whatever w
WHERE (w.user_id, w.branch_id) IN ( ('a','1'), ('b', '2'), ... )
```

or if you have a lot of values, where this starts getting inefficient, join on a temp table. Big `IN` lists are bad whether they're singular values or composite.

Comment: Thanks. I want to use an IN clause because I have a lot of keys to look up. Also, I want to have the keys made of values, not IDs. I should have specified.

Comment: Value, ID, whatever. same principle. Don't concatenate like that, use composite keys.

Comment: Edited, hope that helps. Really, use composite keys.

Comment: IN ( ('a','1'), ('b', '2'), ... ) that really helps, thank you. I used a JOIN, and have fields from multiple tables in the WHERE clause.